# FHIR forge How profile elements that come from base types

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to profile a MessageHeader resource using Forge 26.1.1 for R4.

We need our MessageHeader resource to have an id element in all cases.  The id element comes from Resource.  MessageHeader inherits from DomainResource which inherits from Resource.   How do we specify that the MessageHeader resource has to have an id element, in our MessageHeader profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under 'options', select "Show common resource elements (id, meta, ...)".  You'll then see them and be able to profile them the same as any other element.

Comment: Boom!  Thanks.  seems so obvious now!